# Expand-Collapse feature in gridview

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview, collapsiblepanelextender

I have an ASP.Net default GridView in VS 2008. Now if I click history column, I need to expand column (by clicking right arrow '>') and beneath display the necessary data. It should be collapse when clicking the right arrow again.

One way is using Collapsible Panel of AJAX and other (not sure) is div. But I am not sure how to use either of them inside GridView satisfying the requirement as mentioned above.

Please help me! Let me know if any query.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the generated source and you should see that your ASP.Net GridView renders as a HTML table.  It may not be the best solution but you could use some jQuery to hide all `<td>` and `<th>` of a certain CSS class, ID or name (which you can assign manually in your .aspx) when you click on the button.